# Display armor as an item in head slot

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a game that requires "cards".
I have made, that the armor appear as card in hand, but how can I make a helmet look like other cards in head slot?

Now it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the card as a sword in the head slot works fine, but is there an easy way to texture helmet, so it will look the same in the head slot?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply different transformations to the model of any item based on its position by using `display` tag.

From [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Model#Item_models):

> - **display**: Holds the different places where item models are displayed.
> - **thirdperson**, **firstperson**, **gui**, **head**, **ground**, or **fixed**: Place where an item model is displayed. Holds its rotation, translation and scale for the specified situation. **fixed** refers to item frames, while the rest are as their name states. In [1.9](https://minecraft.wiki/w/1.9),<sup>[[*upcoming*](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Planned_versions)]</sup>, the `"thirdperson"` and `"firstperson"` tags are replaced with `"thirdperson_righthand"`, `"thirdperson_lefthand"`, `"firstperson_righthand"`, and `"firstperson_lefthand"`.
> - **rotation**: Specifies the rotation of the model according to the scheme `[x, y, z]`.
> - **translation**: Specifies the position of the model according to the scheme `[x, y, z]`. If the value is greater than 24, it is displayed as 24. If the value is less than -24, it is displayed as -24.
> - **scale**: Specifies the scale of the model according to the scheme `[x, y, z]`. If the value is greater than 4, it is displayed as 4.